# PHP: Finding the next and previous values of an Array, when there may be "missing" indexes

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm working with some data which is being retrieved from my database. It's placed into a 2-dimensional* array and manually sets the index based upon the ID of the data in the database.

* *It's more than two-dimensional, but I only need to work with 2 dimensions of it.*

This is the Array in question:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Boolean(false)
    [results] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title1
                    [4] => title2
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title3
                    [1] => title4
                    [2] => title5
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title6
                    [1] => title7
                    [3] => title8
                )
        )
)
```

Within this Array, I only need to work with the "results" part of it, hence making the problem Array 2-dimensional.

Some voodoo-magic happens in my script and I'm told the index for the first array and the index for the second array, and then I pull the value from the second array.

Let's say that I wanted to get the value "title5". My script would tell me that I need to use index 3 and then index 2.

I've done all of that, but it's this next part of the task that I'm stuck on, and have no-idea how to even attempt.

After retrieving "title5" I want to retrieve the indexes for the next and previous item, so in this case for both "title4" and "title6". In the event of there not being a previous value (say we originally pulled "title1") then I need some way of identifying this, like with a false boolean. And likewise for if there is no "next" value either.

By retrieve the indexes I mean, for example: `title4 = 3 & 1` and `title6 = 4 & 0`

Does anybody have any ideas how I should go about doing this? I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me necessarily, but some pointers would be greatly appreciated. In the mean time I'll keep experimenting. Thanks!

**Note**:

- Titles aren't actually called `title1`, `title2`, etc. So I can't just decrement a number and do a search.

Comment: When you say you're looking for the next and previous indexes what exactly do you mean?  Are you saying if you retreive title 5, located at $results[3][2]. You would want to know that there was a value at $results[3][1] and $results[4][0]?  I can bang out a quick script for you I just want to be sure I understand what you're looking for :)

Comment: Exactly. If I receive title 5 located at `$results[3][2]` then I wish to know that there is a value at `$results[3][1]` and `$results[4][0]`. I don't need to know what those values are, but I need to know the indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited @Jonathan Rich's answer a little bit to obtain my actual solution. Where `$firstIndex` and `$secondIndex` are the two index that I already know.

```
//my already known indexes
$firstIndex = 3;
$secondIndex = 2;
//
$prevIndex1 = null;
$prevIndex2 = null;
$last_was_value = false;
$nextIndex1 = null;
$nextIndex2 = null;
foreach ( $articles['results'] as $index => $value ) {
    foreach ( $articles['results'][$index] as $index2 => $value2 ) {
        if ( ($index == $firstIndex) && ($index2 == $secondIndex) ) {
            $last_was_value = true;
        } else if ($last_was_value == true) {
            $nextIndex1 = $index;
            $nextIndex2 = $index2;
            break 2;
        } else if ($last_was_value == false) {
            $prevIndex1 = $index;
            $prevIndex2 = $index2;
        }
    }   
}
echo "<br />PREV: $prevIndex1 & $prevIndex2<br />";
echo "NEXT: $nextIndex1 & $nextIndex2<br />";
```

Comment: Bah I was halfway through typing out an alternate solution, but this is basically the same thing.  The only issue you're going to face here is if your array is prohibitively large as you're actually walking the entire array structure.

Comment: Hopefully I shouldn't have too much of a problem with that. I can't ever see this array being larger than a few hundred items. If your solution is better in terms of performance/memory however then feel free to post it and I'll give it a try and accept it if it works - who knows, in the future I may have to do this again with a very large array :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is a low level solution:

```
$prev = null;
$last_was_value = false;
$next = null;

foreach ( $foo['results'][$index1] as $index => $value ) {
    if($value == $some_result_value) {
        $last_was_value = true; 
    } elseif($last_was_value == true && $next == null) {
        $next = $index;
    } elseif($last_was_value == false) {
        $prev = $index;
    }
}
```

So in the end, if prev or next are null, then your index is the first/last index respectively, and if not then those values are the sibling indexes.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, however it's only working on a single dimension. I'm liking the idea that is behind it though and will toy around with that to try and get a working solution.